# What happens to the data in the socket when read and write system calls are used?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

This refers to C sockets. Say I have written some data into the socket, then I call read, will read system call read `buffer size(say 4096 etc)` information and delete all the information in the socket? Basically will read just move the seek pointer forward to those many bytes that it read or will it read and just delete all the information from socket, so that next time when read is called, it reads from the 0th index?

Or say I write into the socket without calling read from anywhere else? Will the data be replaced or appended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is more data available on a socket than the amount that you `read()`, the extra data will be kept in the socket's buffer until you read it. No data is lost during a short read.

Writing works similarly. If you call `write()` multiple times, each write will append data to the buffer on the remote host. Again, no data is lost.

(Eventually, the buffer on the remote host will fill up. When this happens, `write()` will block -- the local host will wait for the buffer to empty before sending more data.)

Conceptually, each direction in a socket pair behaves like a pipe between the two peers. The overall stream of data sent will be received in the same order it was sent, regardless of how much data was read/written at a time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but just to be sure: So when you say that no data is lost, does it also mean that if I have read say 4096 bytes(assume that write occurred before with >4096 bytes written), will I be able to use seek on this socket file descriptor to go back and "re-read" the first 4096 bytes "again"?

Comment: No. `seek()` only works on files -- you can't use it on sockets (or other types of streams, like pipes or FIFOs).

Comment: @Blasttrash No, it doesn't 'also mean' that. You can't seek on a socket.

Comment: So when I have read the first 4096 bytes, are they gone from the socket(deleted from the socket I mean) into my local buffer(that I used as the second argument in read call)?

Comment: @Blasttrash Right. The part that isn't lost is any *additional* data that's waiting in the buffer, beyond the 4096 bytes that you've read.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was what I was looking for. This feature ensures that I can pretty much read stuff again without having to worry about the fact that I may re-read my old content(as long as I was able to read the initial content of course).

Comment: @JohnMike You *can't* 'read stuff again', and nobody here has stated otherwise.